# Can a foreigner on a B1/B2 visa apply for an Irish visa from the Irish embassy in the US?

Tags: visas, usa, ireland, entry-permit

My Sri Lankan friend is planning to visit the USA for a conference. While she is in the USA, she has to apply for an Irish visa, since she doesn't have time to do that after returning to Sri Lanka.

Can a foreigner on a B1/B2 visa apply for an Irish visa from the Irish embassy in the US?

If B1/B2 does not allow this, what is the US visa type that allows this?

Comment: According to http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Visit%20Tourist visit visa applications have to be made from the individual’s home country or place of legal residence

Comment: As it is a long term visa (per your ealier question), would she then plan to stay in the US, pending approval (which can take several months, or more)?

Comment: If the application is for a long term visa, this is probably better on Expatriates.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no, your friend would have to apply in her country of residence, according to the [Irish Naturalisation and Immigration Service](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Frequently%20asked%20questions):

> **Applying for an Irish visa outside of country of residence**
>
> Q.7 I will be travelling to, or I am already in, another country on a short visit before travelling to Ireland. Can I apply for my Irish visa in the Irish Embassy/Consulate/Visa Office there?
>
> No (unless Q8 applies to you). Visa applications should be made in your country of residence. If however, there are valid reasons or extenuating circumstances which prevented you from doing so prior to your departure, you should discuss the matter with staff at the nearest Irish Embassy, Consulate, or Visa Office.
>
> Q.8 I am the immediate family member of a national of an EU Member State. I will be travelling to, or I am already in, another country on a short visit before travelling to Ireland. Can I apply for my Irish visa in the Irish Embassy/Consulate there?
>
> Yes. Your application may be submitted to any Embassy/Consulate however, the staff there do not have to process the application, and may refer the application to the INIS in Dublin, for processing.